# Compare all elements inside a 2D array with each other

Tags: algorithm

I have a perfectly square 64x64 2D array of integers that will never have a value greater than 64. I was wondering if there is a really fast way to compare all of the elements with each other and display the ones that are the same, in a unique way.

At the current moment I have this

```
2D int array named array
loop from i = 0 to 64
    loop from j = 0 to 64
        loop from k = (j+1) to 64
            loop from z = 0 to 64
                if(array[i][j] == array[k][z])
                    print "element [i][j] is same as [k][z]
```

As you see having 4 nested loops is quite a stupid thing that I would like not to use. Language does not matter at all whatsoever, I am just simply curious to see what kind of cool solutions it is possible to use. Since value inside any integer will not be greater than 64, I guess you can only use 6 bits and transform array into something fancier. And that therefore would require less memory and would allow for some really fancy bitwise operations. Alas I am not quite knowledgeable enough to think in that format, and therefore would like to see what you guys can come up with.

Thanks to anyone in advance for a really unique solution.

Comment: Annotate it with the coordinates, then sort it on value, then look at adjacent entries with the same value. Also: Burrows-Wheeler transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to sort the array via an O(m log m) algorithm; you can use an O(m) bucket sort.  (Letting m = n*n = 64*64).

An easy O(m) method using lists is to set up an array H of n+1 integers, initialized to -1; also allocate an array L of `m` integers each, to use as list elements.  For the `i`'th array element, with value A[i], set k=A[i] and L[i]=H[k] and H[k]=i.  When that's done, each H[k] is the head of a list of entries with equal values in them.  For 2D arrays, treat array element A[i,j] as A[i+n*(j-1)].

Here's a python example using python lists, with n=7 for ease of viewing results:

```
import random
n = 7
m = n*n
a=[random.randint(1,n) for i in range(m)]
h=[[] for i in range(n+1)]
for i in range(m):
    k = a[i]
    h[k].append(i)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    print 'With value %2d:  %s' %(i, h[i])
```

Its output looks like:

```
With value  1:  [1, 19, 24, 28, 44, 45]
With value  2:  [3, 6, 8, 16, 27, 29, 30, 34, 42]
With value  3:  [12, 17, 21, 23, 32, 41, 47]
With value  4:  [9, 15, 36]
With value  5:  [0, 4, 7, 10, 14, 18, 26, 33, 38]
With value  6:  [5, 11, 20, 22, 35, 37, 39, 43, 46, 48]
With value  7:  [2, 13, 25, 31, 40]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class temp {
    int i, j;
    int value;
}
```

then fill your array in class temp array[64][64], then sort it by value (you can do this in Java by implementing a comparable interface). Then the equal element should be after each other and you can extract i,j for each other.

This solution would be optimal, categorizing as a quadratic approach for [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: What's O2? Oxygen? Complexity?

Comment: :) i think in algorithm O notation mean the Complexity

Comment: In that case, I presume you meant O(n^2). But further details are important. If you take n=64, then sorting should take O(n^2 * log(n)). If you take n=64^2, then sorting is O(n * log(n)). Likewise, for n=64 a single array traversal is O(n^2), but for n=64^2 it's O(n).

Comment: exactly thanks you for your explanation 
the sorting cost is 64^2 log2(64^2)
and the cost of re looping the array is 64^2
so the all cost is 64^2.log2(64^2)+64^2
however the first way of the four loop take 64^4

Answer (score 1):

Use [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) on the array, then iterate through the array, storing a temporary value of the "cursor" (current value you're looking at), and determine if the temporary value is the same as the next cursor.

```
array[64][64];
quicksort(array);
temp = array[0][0];
for x in array[] {
    for y in array[][] {
        if(temp == array[x][y]) {
            print "duplicate found at x,y";
        }
        temp = array[x][y];
    }
}
```